# Firestore Flutter How Sort Data using int fields

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i have a firestore db with structure
Root
.....Oder
.........Xyz1
______T:1
.........Xyz1
______T:1
when i get the data i want it to sort automatically in  desending oder using the int value stored in 'T'
T is unique for every document

```
child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Oder").snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return new Text('Loading...');
              }
              return new ListView(
                reverse: true,
                children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
                  return new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(document['T'].toString()),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          ),
```

This is my code here
I also have the same value of T as String as each document name so sorting with that gave me 1,10,11,2,3...
So i need to get sorted with the int value stored in T

Answer (score 1):

This is

You can get the data with this line:

```
 CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("data-collection");
```

But , you can get the ordered data with:

```
Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("data-collection").orderBy('field');
```

orderBy should returns a Query, you can no longer store it as a CollectionReference.

Comment: It Gives me an Error when i try stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Oder")..orderBy('T').snapshots(),

Comment: Could you add information about the error you are seeing?